# Can a user share Tableau Trusted authentication Ticket to someone else

Tags: tableau-api

Let's say my web server calls 
Tableau to get a ticket

> POST on https://mytableau/trusted with client_ip parameters

to get a ticket number that we use on an IFrame.

Can the user share it with another person to spoof his login to other?

set

> wgserver.extended_trusted_ip_checking to true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the IP address is same then `wgserver.extended_trusted_ip_checking` is not going to stop userB from using the ticket generated for userA to 'spoof' the login for userA.

That being said, the trusted token is one-time-use only, so as soon as the view is rendered for userA the token becomes useless for userB.

Also there is a time out of 180 seconds after which the ticket expires. (This time can be reduced further by tweaking : `vizqlserver.trustedticket.timeout_in_seconds`)

Comment: Is it possible for the hacker to get the token before my page render?

Comment: Lets take my application as an example. When user click on the 'show dashboard' link in my web app a call goes to a webservice on my webserver. This is the time when my webapp calls tableu to get a trusted ticket, creates the URL of the relevent dashboard using it and passes the URL back as a responce to client browser. My javascripts in client browser takes the URL and creates an IFrame to show it. Everything happens over HTTPS and part of one call. I don't see much scope for a hacker. If your application is somewhat similar, I think your are all set in terms of security.